# UL menu and sub menu not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I´m trying to make Nav menu + sub-menu like this site : http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38913.html I almost get it done. But the problem is I can not get the sub menu to show in the right way when rollvover the link "SERVICE".

**CSS**

```
nav.menu ul {
    position:relative;

}
nav.menu ul li {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(transparenter.png);
    z-index: 10000;
        margin-left: 5px;;
            margin-right: 5px;;

}

nav.menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
}


nav.menu ul li .img-container {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.21, 1.22, 1, 1.31);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
nav.menu ul li .img-top {
  height: 35px;
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.menu ul li .img-top a{
    color:#F60;


}

nav.menu ul li .img-bottom {
  height: 35px;
  width: 120px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav.menu ul li .img-container:hover {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

nav.menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
    width:120px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 22px;
}
nav.menu ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 27px;
}
nav.menu ul li ul li a {
    background-image: url(transparenter.png);
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}
nav.menu ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-image: url(transparenter.png);
}
nav.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
}

nav.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="menu">
<ul>

<li >
<div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-top"><a href="#contact" class="panel">KONTAKT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-bottom">CONTACT</div>
</div>
</li>

<li>
 <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-top"><a href="#service">SERVICE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-bottom">SERVICE</div>


<ul>
                <li><a href="#s1"  class="panel">ITEM 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#s2" class="panel">ITEM 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#s3" class="panel">ITEM 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#s4" class="panel">ITEM 4</a></li>
             <li><a href="#s5" class="panel">ITEM 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div> 
</li>

    <li>
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-top"><a href="#about" class="panel" >OM OSS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-bottom">ABOUT US</div>
  </div>
</li>



  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It's not relevant, but you have a typo in `nav.menu ul li ul` at `widht`

Comment: What do you want to suggest me ?

Comment: In that line you write `widht` instead of `width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this link [FiddleCode](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/zfp4af25/8/).

HTML

```
        <nav class="menu">
<ul>

<li >
    <div class="img-container">
        <div class="img-top"><a href="#contact" class="panel">KONTAKT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-bottom">CONTACT</div>
    </div>
</li>

<li id="serviceUl">
    <div class="img-container">
        <div class="img-top"><a href="#service">SERVICE</a> </div>
        <div class="img-bottom">SERVICE</div>
    </div>
        <ul id="submenu" style="display:none;">
             <li><a href="#s1"  class="panel">ITEM 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#s2" class="panel">ITEM 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#s3" class="panel">ITEM 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#s4" class="panel">ITEM 4</a></li>
             <li><a href="#s5" class="panel">ITEM 5</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>

    <li>
      <div class="img-container">
        <div class="img-top"><a href="#about" class="panel" >OM OSS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-bottom">ABOUT US</div>
      </div>
    </li>



  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS

```
.empty{
    height:600px;background:#ddd;
}
nav{
    height:60px;
    background:#000;
}
nav.menu ul {
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
}
nav.menu ul li {
    float:right;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(transparenter.png);
    z-index: 999;
        margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;

}

nav.menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
}


nav.menu ul li .img-container {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.21, 1.22, 1, 1.31);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
nav.menu ul li .img-top {
  height: 35px;

  width: 120px;

  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.menu ul li .img-top a{
    color:#F60;


}

nav.menu ul li .img-bottom {
  height: 35px;
  width: 120px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav.menu ul li .img-container:hover {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

ul#submenu {
    width:120px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999999;
    background:#000;
}
nav.menu ul li ul#submenu li {
    float: none;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow:auto;
}



nav.menu ul li#serviceUl:hover ul#submenu {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999999;top:60px
}
```

understand this code and implement same like. don't give  position relatives and absolute for all elements. Follow z-index based on requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And sorry for late reply due to I haven´r checkec this for a while because I thought there´s nobody will give the answer. I am happy now.

But one question, When I rollover on service and try to rollover on the sub menu but why it always disappear ? SOmething wrong ?

Comment: I think in their site http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38913.html they are used some jquery function based on time to display the sub menu's and all. That's why the sub menu is displaying. so you can see those functions and all.

Comment: @user3384389: I think in their site http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38913.html they are used some jquery function based on time to display the sub menu's and all. That's why the sub menu is displaying. so you can see those functions and all.